# How to update the Circular Percentage Indicator once we click each Checkbox List

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to do the checklist section which have circular percentage indicator. The percentage should updated once the list of checklist(checkbox) is clicked. Each Checkbox should hold 25% because have 4 checklist and the overall percentage is 100. Please help me how to update the percentage.

[This is the interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IsDl.png)

```
class ReportForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final int itemIndex;
  final Project project;
  const ReportForm({this.itemIndex, this.project});

  @override
  State<ReportForm> createState() => _ReportFormState();
}

class _ReportFormState extends State<ReportForm> {
  FirebaseFirestore _firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  UserModel loggedInUser = UserModel();
  double progress = 0.0;
  currentProgressColor() {
    if (progress >= 0.6 && progress < 0.8) {
      return Colors.red;
    }
    if(progress >= 0.8){
      return Colors.green;
    }
    else{
      return Colors.orange;
    }
  }

  final checklist = [
    CheckBoxState(title: 'Attendance'),
    CheckBoxState(title: 'Equipment Used'),
    CheckBoxState(title: 'Work Performed'),
    CheckBoxState(title: 'Remarks'),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Container(
          height: 650,
          width: 370,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                offset: Offset(0, 1),
                blurRadius: 17,
                spreadRadius: -23,
                color: kShadowColor,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height:40,
              ),
              CircularPercentIndicator(
                radius: 200.0,
                circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
                lineWidth: 25.0,
                progressColor: currentProgressColor(),
                percent: progress,
                animation: true,
                animationDuration: 1500,
                center: new Text("${this.progress * 100}%", style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30,
                ),),
                footer: new Text("Daily Report Completion",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),),),
              SizedBox(
                height:20,
              ),
              StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: _firebaseFirestore.collection("Attendance").snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => Attendance(
                        ),
                      ));
                    },
                    child: Card(
                      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13.0)
                      ),
                      elevation: 10,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 2.0, 10.0, 2.0),
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        width: 350,
                        height:60,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                          child: buildSingleCheckbox(CheckBoxState(title: 'Attendance')),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height:18,
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => DetailsForm(project: widget.project, itemIndex: widget.itemIndex),
                  ));
                },
                child: Card(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13.0)
                  ),
                  elevation: 10,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 2.0, 10.0, 2.0),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    width: 350,
                    height: 60,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                      child: buildSingleCheckbox(CheckBoxState(title: 'Equipment Used')),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height:18,
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => HomeScreen(),
                  ));
                },
                child: Card(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13.0)
                  ),
                  elevation: 10,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 2.0, 10.0, 2.0),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    width: 350,
                    height: 60,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                      child: buildSingleCheckbox(CheckBoxState(title: 'Work Performed')),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height:18,
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Remarks(),
                  ));
                },
                child: Card(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13.0)
                  ),
                  elevation: 10,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 2.0, 10.0, 2.0),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    width: 350,
                    height: 60,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                      child: buildSingleCheckbox(CheckBoxState(title: 'Remarks')),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

  Widget buildSingleCheckbox(CheckBoxState checkbox) => StatefulBuilder(
    builder: (context, _setState) => CheckboxListTile(
      activeColor: Colors.green,
      value: checkbox.value,
      title: Text(checkbox.title),
      onChanged: (value) =>
        _setState(() => checkbox.value = value),
    ),
  );
}

class CheckBoxState{
  final String title;
  bool value;

  CheckBoxState({
  @required this.title,
  this.value = false,});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a small test you can apply according to your need

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/circular_percent_indicator.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Teste',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Teste(),
    );
  }
}

class Teste extends StatefulWidget {
  const Teste({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TesteState createState() => _TesteState();
}

class _TesteState extends State<Teste> {
  List<bool> checkboxStatus = [];
  double percentage = 0.0;
  final checklist = ['Attendance', 'Equipment Used', 'Work Performed', 'Remarks'];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checklist.forEach((element) => checkboxStatus.add(false));
  }

  currentProgressColor() {
    if (percentage >= 0.6 && percentage < 0.8) {
      return Colors.red;
    }
    if (percentage >= 0.8) {
      return Colors.green;
    } else {
      return Colors.orange;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Container(
          height: 650,
          width: 370,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13),
            boxShadow: [BoxShadow(offset: Offset(0, 1), blurRadius: 17, spreadRadius: -23, color: Colors.orange)],
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 40),
              CircularPercentIndicator(
                animateFromLastPercent: true,
                radius: 200.0,
                circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
                lineWidth: 25.0,
                progressColor: currentProgressColor(),
                percent: percentage,
                animation: true,
                animationDuration: 1500,
                center: Text('${percentage * 100} %'),
                footer: Text("Daily Report Completion", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.green)),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: checklist.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Card(
                        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13.0)),
                        elevation: 10,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (checklist[index] == 'Attendance') {
                              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Attendance()));
                            } else if() {
                              /// other page
                            }
                          },
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.white),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Text(checklist[index], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                              Checkbox(
                                value: checkboxStatus[index],
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  if (checkboxStatus[index] == false) {
                                    percentage += (1 / checklist.length);
                                  } else {
                                    percentage -= (1 / checklist.length);
                                  }
                                  setState(() => checkboxStatus[index] = !checkboxStatus[index]);
                                },
                                checkColor: Colors.white,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried and it works! but I have a problem to link it to another page. For example, when I click for Attendance, it will go to the Attendance page. I am sorry for the trouble, I am still new with flutter. Can you add the code there for each clicked to their respective page?

Comment: @Adila I changed my answer